# Visual Studio 2015 with 2012(v110) toolset

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to build an application (Qt specifically) in Visual Studio 2015 but using 2012 toolset (cause 2015 redistributable requires Windows update where my client does not want to do that). I've try to change the project properties->Configuration properties->Platform Toolset to Visual Studio 2012 (v110) and modify the .vcxproj file as image below.

[image]

but when i try to compile the project error occurs.

[image]

Following the error, in the Microsoft.CppCommon.targets file, the error shows at this line.

```
<CL Condition="'%(ClCompile.PrecompiledHeader)' != 'Create' and '%(ClCompile.ExcludedFromBuild)'!='true' and '%(ClCompile.CompilerIteration)' == ''"
```

Have totally no idea what error is it about.

Need some help here..

Using v140(2015) toolset compile successfully.

Comment: Don't edit project files by hand. Changing "Platform toolset" in Visual Studio via Project -> Settings is the only change required.

Comment: Also, if this is a Qt project, you should use `qmake` and it will yield the correct project files immediately. You need a version of Qt that's built with 2012, and its `qmake` will do just what you need.

Comment: My Qt version was build for msvc2015, guess it will be a hassle to rebuild the whole project in Qt msvc2012?

Comment: You cannot link your 2012 project against 2015 Qt. You need the Qt version built with 2012. It's available in the online installer for Qt 5. And once you have the right Qt build, the rest is just a matter of running its `qmake`.

Comment: Yup, I had the 2012 Qt version, still having the same error. I've tried to run the Visual Studio 2012, which I found that, it produce the same error as well. "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application." The decimal value reported in VS output -1073741701 is the 0xc000007b in hex. Where I think thats the main culprit of the whole thing. Still investigating the issue..

Comment: It just can't find the Qt 2012 `dll` files. Copy them to where your .exe is, orr add the Qt/bin folder to `PATH`, or add it to project properties -> Debug -> Environment.

Answer (score 0):

One day I read to be able to switch Platform toolset you had to install the corresponding Visual Studio version. and then in vs2015 you are able to switch to v120 or v100 regarding if you had installed VS 2012 or VS2010.

Regarding this post :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770576.aspx

Maybe you can do the trick with just installing SDK.

Comment: I uninstall everything, including VS2015 and VS2012, restarted my PC, and reinstall again VS2012, and it seems like VS2012 is UNABLE to open, with the error "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application." So i suppose this is the problem. I am not sure why my PC unable to install the VS2012. My PC running Win10 x64.

Comment: In which order you did the installation ? I noticed I had to install first VS2010 then 2012 then 2015. As far as I remember as well on 2012 we have to enable C++ somewhere.

Comment: I think I found the issue. The VC++ redistributable packages installation got goofed up. Uninstalling all (including vs2012 and the redistributable packages) and reinstall a fresh VS2012 works fine. Now I am trying to reinstall the 2015 and see if downgrading the platform toolset works fine.

Comment: at least in my environment on my laptop with VS2010 / VS2012/VS2013/VS2015 I can choose all platform toolset. It should work.

Comment: No it doesn't. Well, the above error goes away (as I mentioned before, it is because of the redistributable issue), now it has another issue with the clxxx.dll file.

Comment: It works! The issue is just the VC++ redistributable that is not installed properly (I supposed) and I reinstall them and it works!